# Show the following map is jointly convex.

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems

The map $(A,B) \rightarrow Tr[A \log(A)] - Tr[A\log(B)]$ from $H_n^+ \times H_n^+$ to $R$ is jointly convex.

I have the following proof but I do not understand it.
I can write it, but I would appreciate it if you could explicitly explain or give another solution to it.

For all $0<p<1 , (A,B) \rightarrow Tr(B^{1-p}A^p)$, we show $(a,b)$ is convex and that convexity is conserved.

Comment: Did you get the proof from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequalities#Proof_2)? It says a bit more there.

Comment: @A.Γ. Yes, it is from Wikipedia but I do not really get the details. The function we are talking about is convex and when we use the limit we get the relative quantum entropy. Would appreciate some explicit explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It is three steps proof:

1. Apply Lieb's concavity theorem to conclude that
   $$
   (A,B)\mapsto \text{Tr}\,(B^{1-p}A^p)
   $$
   is jointly concave.
2. Construct a new function
   $$
   (A,B)\mapsto \underbrace{\frac{1}{p-1}}_{\text{negative}}\Big(\underbrace{\text{Tr}\,(B^{1-p}A^p)-\text{Tr}\,A}_{\text{concave}}\Big).
   $$
   It is convex (=minus concave).
3. Limit of convex functions is convex. Note that the limit of the function i Step 2 when $p\to 1$ is the derivative of the function at $p=1$. Take the derivative w.r.t. $p$
   $$
   (A,B)\mapsto \text{Tr}\,(-B^{1-p}\log(B)\, A^p+B^{1-p}A^p\log(A))
   $$
   and set $p=1$. Change the order of $A$ and $\log(B)$ under trace (possible). Done.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But how do we know that the trace(A) is a concave function? @A.Γ.

Comment: @gmath tr(A) is a linear function of A (and (A,B), of course). Any linear is concave (and convex). Easy by definition. Sum of concave is concave.

Comment: @gmath It will be a great exercise if you write down here your complete proof from my sketch, and we will give you feedback on details.